# Is is possible to change MAC address of a WiMAX USB adapter?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, mac-address, wimax

Wondering if it is possible to change the MAC address of a **WiMAX** USB adapter (read WiMAX, not Wi-Fi) manufactured by Motorola, ZTE, Intel etc. I've tried a few tools that did changed the MAC address of the adapter to another valid MAC address (that I coped from another equipment made by same company) but then I was not able to connect to the network, the connection software took long time stating "obtaining IP address"; then few seconds after it got one said "lost IP address". Wondering if changing MAC address of such devices actually work.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to change the MAC address with the motorola WiMax dongles that use the Motorola Connection manager. There is a hidden menu, and it can be changed in there. I don't remember the exact command to change it, and I don't have the software installed currently, but to access the hidden menu, go to the Profiles menu then hit: Ctrl + Shift + Alt + ~

Also, Intel only makes internal cards. It is not possible(unless you have the development tools, that are only available for intel employees)  to change the mac.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite surprising that you would want to change the MAC for your USB Adapter.
Is there a *good* reason for attempting that?

However, it is a very interesting requirement (for whatever reason) and I am intrigued to know if this can be done. I think it cannot be done -- unless the manufacturer introduced a low-level path to support that maybe... and, what need would that be based on?

There is one discussion on the subject at this Ubuntuforums thread,
[USB Wi-Fi Adaptor for MAC Address Change](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1506928)
See if it helps you.
One suggestion is to check the manufacturer site for supporting instructions or software.
<sup>ps: [one more reference](http://forums.speedguide.net/showthread.php?t=238093) on the same lines.</sup>

---

Update:
If they gave you a complementary USB Adapter for the service, they should have a mechanism to allow binding both for authentication. They should be able to regulate your access to allow only one at a time. Otherwise the complementary device has no use. Check with them on this.

Comment: My internet service provider gave me two devices: a regular WiMAX router and a complimentary USB WiMAX adapter (to carry around with my laptop). Now that they've implemented MAC address authentication I was asked to provide MAC address of the "preferred" device so that they can "bind" my account with that MAC address and I cannot therefore use the USB adapter anymore. I need to use the USB device on occasions such as when I am traveling therefore trying to "spoof" the same MAC address as that of the router (but I'll use one device at a time).

Answer (score 0):

As for Windows, some NIC drivers will let you manually enter a MAC.  The Intel NIC driver for my PC does (see pic below).  Check the properties of your NIC from the `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections`

[image: LAN Properties Dialog]

If you can not do it from there, there are other methods.  This [article](http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/changemac) gives you some options for a variety of OSs.